# How to compare two text box value in infopathDesigner 2013?

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

I using Info path-designer 2013

Need to compare the  Two Text Box Data type is string.

value of First text and Second Text box Need to be compare.

But i store second Text Box String like this Job1,job2,job3,jo4,job5

Now my need is

If i enter Job1 in first text box then i need to compare the value with second text box.

From the above example Job1 is present in second text box so i show true

but i enter Job6 in first text box i need to show False

it's possible to Do...?

Example 1:-

```
Box1(Text box)    Job1
Box2(Text Box)    Job1,Job2,Job3,Job4,Job5

Result(Text box) TRUE
```

Example 2:-

```
 Box1(Text box)    Job6
 Box2(Text Box)    Job1,Job2,Job3,Job4,Job5

 Result(Text box) FALSE
```

I try with Contains formula it's not working.

If there is any alternate option please tell me

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

Under`Manage Rules` select `Action` Rule

In action Under `condition:`, but `Box1 contains Box2`

In `run this action` add `set a field's value` in that

Select the field `box3`

put the value `True`

For next one

In action Under `condition:`, but `Box1 does not contains Box2`

In `run this action` add `set a field's value` in that

select the field `box3`

put the value `False`